# Effects in Adobe Audition to make a voice sound like it's coming from inside a body / in your head

Tags: editing, effects, adobe, audio-drama

I'm editing a radio play and one of the characters is a heart, as in, the beating heart of another character. Does anyone know any effects I could use in Adobe Audition that I could use on the voice? The aim is to differentiate it from other voices in the play and possibly make it sound like it's coming from inside someone's body.

On a separate issue, what effect could I use to make it sound like someone's talking to themselves, in their head (i.e. to differentiate their voice from when they're having a conversation out loud).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Mess around with EQ. Try lowering the treble a bit to muffle the sound. Normally, you would put a low pass filter on to make it sound a bit muffled. As for talking to him\herself, Increase the bass a bit, and do not apply reverb to it. In film, we typically have room tone, reverb and shave off most of the low frequencies to give it the sound of being in a room or outside.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everything but the "do not add reverb." That's where the inside one's head effect comes from. "We" in the film industry cut low frequencies for a number of reasons, mainly because the "mud" lives there. 150 and below.. Also because most devices that audio is being listened to on now-a-days, can't translate that range of frequencies anyways.

Id roll off 4K and above, add some reverb and maybe even some delay for your desired effect. Just trying to help..

--
Returning a favor

Comment: Thanks both for your help, I'll try your suggestions and see what works.